# Accessing values in backed bean showing null values

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have a JSF page where I pass a value to another bean by setting it .The other bean corresponds to another bean and I am able to retrieve the value in the other JSF page .But when I modify the same value am getting null values in backing bean

Let me site the exact an example .I have a list  of products displayed in a page which has a backing bean ProductList.java .Now i have another intermediate bean name ProductAction.java which contains a reference of ProductList.java and ProductDisplay.java which is my other bean in discussion .I need to traverse to the other JSF page and edit the product and save the product .

Now when I reach the ProductAction via command button invoke am getting null values .

Can anyone advice

Comment: How exactly are you referencing `ProductList` inside `ProductAction`?

Comment: could the problem be that the beans are `view` scoped?

Comment: Yes indeed the beans were view scoped and I removed them to work fine..Thanks for your answers

Comment: I was also first doing a get on the bean instead of directly accessing the properties

Answer (score 0):

Whatever Properties of Java files want to access in other pages or inside other java class must set that class object (means all property of class) in session then only u can get that value to all java files.

Example....

Class_name sm;

ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
extContext.getSessionMap().put("Give name for access this property",sm);

Class_name sm = (Class_name) extContext.getSessionMap().get("Give name for access this property");